# Modal Boostrap reduz o tamanho do corpo do site

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Meu `modal` está diminuindo o tamanho da página horizontalmente quando aberto, ao fechar ele volta a página ao normal, é algo que chega a ser estranho.

Aqui o código:

```
<div class="row" align="right">
    <strong>Posição: <?php echo date("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime($rslt_query_time['data'])); ?></strong>
</div>

<div class="row" align="center">
<div class=" panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">MPF - Gestão de Convênios</h3>
        </div>
        <table style="width: 100%" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr style="cursor:default;">
                <th style="text-align: center; width: 85px; vertical-align:middle">Convênio</th>
                <th data-original-title="Agência Centralizadora" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-container="body" style="text-align: center; width: 85px; vertical-align:middle">Ag. Ctrl.</th>
                <th style="text-align: left; vertical-align:middle">Nome</th>
                <th style="text-align: center; width: 85px; vertical-align: middle;" >Situa&ccedil;&atilde;o</th>
                <th data-original-title="Bloqueio de Contratação" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-container="body" style="text-align: center; width: 85px; vertical-align:middle">Bloqueio</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
    <?php do{?>
            <tr style="cursor:pointer" id="<?php echo $rslt_query['id'];?>" onclick="contato(this)">
                <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $rslt_query['id']; ?></td>
                <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $rslt_query['centralizadora']; ?></a></td>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><?php echo $rslt_query['nome']; ?></td>
<?php               if($rslt_query['situacao'] == 0){ 
                        echo "<td style=\"text-align: center;\" data-original-title=\"Suspenso\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"top\" data-container=\"body\">
                              <img src=\"img/error-icon_32px.png\" alt=\"Suspenso\" /></td>";
                    }else if($rslt_query['situacao'] == 1){ 
                        echo "<td style=\"text-align: center;\" data-original-title=\"Ativo\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"top\" data-container=\"body\" >
                              <img src=\"img/select-icon_32px.png\" alt=\"Ativo\" /></td>";
                    }?>
                <?php
                    $txt_temp = "";
                    if ( $rslt_query['A'] || $rslt_query['B'] || $rslt_query['C'] || $rslt_query['D'] || $rslt_query['E'] || $rslt_query['F']){
                        if($rslt_query['A'] == 1){$txt_temp .= "...<hr>";}
                        if($rslt_query['B'] == 1){$txt_temp .= "...<hr>";}
                        if($rslt_query['C'] == 1){$txt_temp .= "...<hr>";}
                        if($rslt_query['D'] == 1){$txt_temp .= "...<hr>";}
                        if($rslt_query['E'] == 1){$txt_temp .= "...<hr>";}
                        if($rslt_query['F'] == 1){$txt_temp .= "...<hr>";}

                    }
                    $txt_temp .= "";    
                ?>
                <td style="text-align: center;" <?php if($rslt_query['A'] || $rslt_query['B'] || $rslt_query['C'] || $rslt_query['D'] || $rslt_query['E'] || $rslt_query['F']){ echo "data-content=\"".$txt_temp."\" data-html=\"true\" rel=\"popover\" data-placement=\"top\" data-toggle=\"popover\" data-original-title=\"Motivo\" data-trigger=\"hover\" data-container=\"body\" "; }?>>
                <?php if($rslt_query['A'] || $rslt_query['B'] || $rslt_query['C'] || $rslt_query['D'] || $rslt_query['E'] || $rslt_query['F']){ ?><img src="img/alert-icon_32px.png" alt="Suspenso" />
                    <?php }?>
                </td>
            </tr>
<?php }while($rslt_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_db)); ?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
<?php $rslt_query = mysql_data_seek($query_db, 0);

    do{ ?>
    <div id="modal-<?php echo $rslt_query['id'];?>" class="modal fade">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo $rslt_query['nome']; ?></h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <p style="text-align:left;">
                                    <!-- <strong>Nome Convenio:</strong> <?php echo $rslt_query['nome']; ?><br /> -->
                                    <strong>N&ordm; Conv&ecirc;nio:</strong> <?php echo $rslt_query['id']; ?><br />
                                    <strong>MCI:</strong> <?php echo $rslt_query['mci']; ?><br /><br />
                                    <strong>Gestor do Conv&ecirc;nio:</strong> <?php echo $rslt_query['nome_func']; ?><br />
                                    <strong>Chave:</strong> <?php echo strtoupper($rslt_query['chave_func']); ?><br /><br />
                                    <strong>Respons&aacute;vel Financeiro:</strong> <?php echo $rslt_query['resp_fin_nome']; ?><br />
                                    <strong>Telefone:</strong> <?php echo $rslt_query['resp_fin_fone']; ?><br /><br />
                                    <strong>Respons&aacute;vel T&eacute;cnico:</strong> <?php echo $rslt_query['resp_tec_nome']; ?><br />
                                    <strong>Telefone:</strong> <?php echo $rslt_query['resp_tec_fone']; ?><br /><br />
                                    <strong>Fluxo ag&ecirc;ncia:</strong><br/> <?php echo nl2br($rslt_query['fluxo_agencia_propria']); ?><br /><br />
                                    <strong>Fluxo outras agências:</strong><br/> <?php echo nl2br($rslt_query['fluxo_outras_agencias']); ?> <br />

                              </p>
                          </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <?php if((isset($_SESSION['prefDep']) && $rslt_query['centralizadora'] == $_SESSION['prefDep']) || (isset($_SESSION['prefDep']) && $_SESSION['prefDep'] == "8501") ){
                                        echo "<form class=\"form-inline\" id=\"id".$rslt_query['id']."\" action=\"form_convenio_alterar.php\" method=\"post\">";
                                        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=\"" . $rslt_query['id'] . "\">";
                                        echo "</form>";
                                        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" onClick=\"document.getElementById('id".$rslt_query['id']."').submit()\" >Editar</button>";
                                      }
                                 ?>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
<?php
    }while($rslt_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_db));
?>
```

O CSS que uso é o que o Bootstrap disponibiliza, sem nenhuma modificação.

O `body` está assim:

```
<body style="width: 800px; overflow-y:scroll; margin: 0 auto; padding-top: 70px; padding-bottom: 30px;">
```

E aqui o que ocorre:

[image: Diferença de Tamanho]

Comment: Se vc retirar o style do body fica normal? Pode ser uma incompatibilidade entre o modal e esse style no body... Postar a parte de cima do código da página principal pode ajudar.

Comment: Mesmo retirando o Style e jogando as configurações pro CSS ele continua reduzindo de tamanho, só que agora em ambos os lados

Comment: Então, mas sem essas configurações de estilo (nem no CSS) fica certo? Se ficar, dá pra fazer o mesmo efeito desse estilo sem mexer na tag body (na tag ou por css), apenas trabalhando com os grids. Acho que não é muito "natural" pro bootstrap que vc faça esta estilização do `body`. Mas não tenho certeza, poste o código todo que pode ajudar a entender o que está havendo...

Comment: @gustavox http://pastebin.com/CWb86975 parte inicial do código, o conv_table_results.php está postado acima!

Comment: Coloca o script do modal entre as tags `head`, ele tá fora do head e fora do `body`, pode ser isso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consegui resolver meu problema, não sei se futuramente pode me acarretar algum prejuízo, porém, por hora é aceitável

No arquivo `bootstrap.js` na linha 964
Na parte da function

```
Modal.prototype.show
```

Há esta parte

```
this.setScrollbar()
```

Comentei ela e meu problema foi resolvido, toda vez que o modal é aberto ocorre a inserção de um `padding-rigth: 15px` no `body`, achei a solução olhando o código com o inspetor de código do Opera!

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde galera, resolvi o problema adicionando:

```
<style>
    body {
        padding-right: 0 !important;
    }
</style>
```

a resposta anterior do amigo me ajudou muito. obrigado mesmo.